# NotificationCenter is observing multiple times

Tags: swift, observers, notificationcenter

I'm having a problem in my implementation using observers in `Swift`, The problem is I'm having the same observer multiple times so I make one function more than once.

How can I validate if I'm observing the same observer already before observing it again?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunction(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "SameObserver"), object: nil)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making sure to balance your calls to `addObserver` and `removeObserver`. Alternately, you could create a boolean somewhere that indicates that you've already called `addObserver`, but it's better just to balance your calls.

The best way to balance your calls is to tie them to the observer's lifetime or lifecycle. For lifetime you would call `addObserver` in `init` and `removeObserver` in `deinit` (or use one of the forms that automatically removes your observation). For lifecycle (for example in a ViewController), you would call `addObserver` in `viewWillAppear` and `removeObserver` in `viewDidDisappear`.

There is no mechanism for querying NotificationCenter.